# How to overwrite existing worksheet with new dataframe in a multisheet Excel workbook using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an `xlsx` file with multiple sheets: `sheet1, sheet2, sheet3`

```
# Clean up header issues:
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
sheets = xl.sheet_names
for i in sheets:
    df = xl.parse(i)
    df = df[df['Symbol'] != 'Symbol']
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

In the above, I am trying to remove multiple header lines and then I want to overwrite the dataframe to the same file.

I am looking at the documentation and can't seem to figure out a straightforward solution, I can make it work in a roundabout way. Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a read_excel function that also gives you the option to specify the sheet name. You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

file = r'C:\...\file.xlsx' #wherever your excel file is
sheets = ['sheet1', 'sheet2'] # whatever and however many you have
df = {}
for sheet in sheets:
    df[sheet] = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=sheet)
    df[sheet] = df[sheet][df[sheet]['Symbol'] != 'Symbol']
```

If you wanted to export it too then you can just add to the for loop with the pd.to_excel() function

Comment: I can easily create a new file, yes. I am looking to see if there is a way to write back to the same file and sheet. While keeping the rest of the sheets intact.

Comment: You can, all you'd have to do is add the to_excel function like I mentioned with the same options